# OpenWRT - Install Apache - Barrier Breaker 14.07

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, packages, openwrt

I'm trying to find an Apache package for the Barrier Breaker 14.07, however there doesn't appear to be one in the package repository.  Also I can't seem to find one online, I have been searching through Google and just can't find anything to suggest there is one available?

Has anyone ever used OpenWRT Barrier Breaker and managed to get Apache onto their device?
There is no LAMP stack either - the only thing I can find is nginx (however what I want to do appears to be quite difficult with nginx).

The device I'm using is a TP-Link WR703N (a modified version of the WR702)

Comment: Only my personal impression. OpenWRT seems to be a _light system_ for router.  Apache and LAMP stack are not light at all. Are you sure that someone did it before? Have you seen inside the [management package](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/packages) if there is something you can use?

Comment: In all honesty, I'm going by the information that I found online, it was linked with Barrier Breaker, however this could have just been a red herring.  I do have another question then with regards to nginx, which is my alternative, however i'm not so familiar with it.  I'm trying to set up multiple sites & failing, but I will ask this separately.